# docker0 is missing when I reinstall docker

Tags: kubernetes

the all step is in http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/master/#setting-up-flanneld-and-etcd.
all above is passed when I restart docker service,
terminal output is ,
docker.log output is .
I try to reinstall docker,but the docker0 bridge is missing,also can't start the docker service.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is about the --bip=${FLANNEL_SUBNET} --mtu=${FLANNEL_MTU}.
the ${FLANNEL_SUBNET} and ${FLANNEL_MTU} should be enter the numeral get from the flanner container running output.